# Get the real distance between two OpenCV ArUco markers

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

How can I get the real distance between two ArUco markers in a frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1) Get `tvec`

First we need to get the `tvec` of each marker like seen in this one:
[How to get distance from camera to marker with ArUco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68019526/how-can-i-get-the-distance-from-my-camera-to-an-opencv-aruco-marker)

#### 2) Euclidean distance

Once we have both `tvec` 's of both markers in the frame we can simply use the [Euclidean distance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) to retrieve the distance between both markers in the 3D space. Be aware that the unit you'll receive is the same as the one you provided for the real maker size to get the `tvec`.

[Numpy provides a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy) to retrieve the euclidian distance.

```py
np.linalg.norm(tvec1-tvec2)
```